# How to use social glyphicons in bootstrap implemented web page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm not able to use social media glyph-icons in bootstrap implemented web page.
I was able to use the usual ones like search, globe and many more.

This is how I used the usual ones:

```
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-search"></span>
```

How can you implement the above method for the social glyphicons?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The [glyphicons that come free with Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons) is a subset of the [full paid Glyphicons library](http://www.glyphicons.com/) and doesn't include the social media icons set.

Instead, you can use [**Font Awesome**](https://fontawesome.com/), a free alternative that is fully supported (and the preferred icon kit in [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/extend/icons/)), which has a free brand icon set:

[image]

#### [Font Awesome Version 4 - Brands](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/#brand) -  Demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/y4tS8/) & Stack Snippets:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-bitbucket"></i>
<i class="fa fa-digg"></i>
<i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
<i class="fa fa-flickr"></i>
<i class="fa fa-foursquare"></i>
<i class="fa fa-github"></i>
<i class="fa fa-google"></i>
<i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
<i class="fa fa-jsfiddle"></i>
<i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
<i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
<i class="fa fa-reddit"></i>
<i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
<i class="fa fa-soundcloud"></i>
<i class="fa fa-spotify"></i>
<i class="fa fa-stack-exchange"></i>
<i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
<i class="fa fa-steam"></i>
<i class="fa fa-stumbleupon"></i>
<i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i>
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
<i class="fa fa-vimeo-square"></i>
<i class="fa fa-vine"></i>
<i class="fa fa-windows"></i>
<i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i>
<i class="fa fa-yahoo"></i>
<i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>



<style type="text/css">
  .fa {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 200px;
  }

  .fa::before {
    display: inline-block;
    /* .fa-fw */
    width: 1.28571429em;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .fa::after {
    content: attr(class);
    font-family: consolas, monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    /* .code */
    padding: 2px 4px;
    color: #c7254e;
    background-color: #f9f2f4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
</style>
```

#### For **Font Awesome 5**, you can still use brands with the separate [brands bundle](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&s=brands):

```
<i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
```

Comment: But,will the above glyphicon format,work for Bootstrap framework?

Comment: @user3620928, most definitely!  Font Awesome was built with the bootstrap framework in mind, and has backward compatibility with glyphicons. For a while glyphicons were not even shipped with Bootstrap.  They're back now, but most bootstrappers I know prefer FA.

Comment: fontawseome has lot of issue showing in some browsers ad not showing in some, especially IOS safari and chrome

Comment: Note that with Font Awesome 5 the Brands icons should use the `fab` class rather than the `fa` class so it should now be `<i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>`

Comment: @MikePoole, thanks Mike.  I elaborated on the different versions of FA and BS a little to help expand on the updates since the point in time of the original answer

Answer (score 21):

paste this in your code's head part

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and just an example for inserting facebook icon

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
```

For the whole list of glyph-icons, visit https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Answer (score 0):

If using font-awesome 5 the classes have changed.

Now you have more prefixes than just fa: `fab, fas, far, fal`.

To show the twitter logo for instance you need something like this

`<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>`.

You can read more about migrating from font-awesome  4 to 5 [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4).